# To compare the two tables in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, pivot-table

I have two table like below:

```
Table_1  

Customer    Order 
----------------------
David       Pizza
David       Cola
Jack        Milkshake
Michael     Pizza
Michael     Milkshake
Alan        Cola
Alan        Pizza

Table_2

Customer    Order
----------------------
David       Pizza
David       Cola
Jack        Milkshake
Michael     Pizza
Michael     Milkshake
Alan        Milkshake
Alan        Pizza
```

I have code like this (I wrote Request instead of Order):

```
 WITH t AS
 (SELECT customer
    ,row_number() over(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY "ORDER" DESC) order_no
     ,"ORDER"
     ,COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY customer) order_cnt
  FROM   table_1)
  SELECT customer, order1, order2, order3, order_cnt "Counts of Orders"
  FROM   t
  pivot (MAX("ORDER") FOR order_no IN(1 AS order1, 2 AS order2,AS order3))
  ORDER  BY customer;
```

It is making this:

```
  Table_1

 Customer     order1     order2     order3  counts of orders
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 David        pizza      cola       null            2
 Jack        milkshake   null       null            1
 Michael      pizza    milkshake    null            2
 Alan         cola      pizza        null           2
```

I implemented the code Table_2 and it is making this:

```
Customer     Order1     Order2    Order3     Counts of Orders
-------------------------------------------------------------
 David       Pizza      Cola       null             2
 Jack        Milkshake  null       null             1
 Michael     Pizza      Milkshake  null             2
 Alan        Milkshake   Pizza      null            2
```

I want to compare these tables. For example: David ordered pizza and cola in Table_1 and Table_2. It is true.

But Alan ordered cola, pizza in Table_1 and milkshake, pizza in Table_2
I want to see differences between Table_1 and Table_2.

I have only that code and my tables seem like Table_1 and Table_2.
When I wrote the code, I see orders in both Table_1 and Table_2.

But I want to see differences between them.

Comment: There is no need for Pivot here. Google : `SQL-Server group concat`

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in Oracle and cannot be used as a column name (unless you surround it with double quotes of course). There is no way the query you posted actually works at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
WITH t AS
 (SELECT customer
        ,row_number() over(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY "ORDER" DESC) order_no
         ,"ORDER"
         ,COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY customer) order_cnt
  FROM   table_1)
SELECT customer, order1, order2, order3, order_cnt "Counts of Orders"
FROM   t
pivot (MAX("ORDER") FOR order_no IN(1 AS order1, 2 AS order2, 3 AS order3))
ORDER  BY customer;
```

Here is my result:

```
CUSTOME ORDER1    ORDER2    ORDER3    Counts of Orders
------- --------- --------- --------- ----------------
David   Pizza     Cola                               2
Jack    Milkshake                                    1
Michael Pizza     Milkshake                          2

3 rows selected.
```